# Making a "virtual" drive?

Tags: macos

I want to make a virtual flash drive on OSX so I can install something onto it and then back that virtual flash drive up to an iso so I can boot it into a virtual machine... Any ideas on how something like this would be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about VirtualBox?

You can get it's preconfigured .vdi iamges online, which are similar to iso files in your case, and you can boot from any of these vdi files via the virtualbox software...

To create a vdi, you'll have to first download the OS installation iso.... then load that iso to virtualbox, along with it's hardware/network/etc settings, and once created you can copy the created vdi and run from any computer via the virtualbox.

Link : https://www.virtualbox.org/

It's also available for OS X hosts...: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

> **VirtualBox** is a powerful x86 and AMD64/Intel64 virtualization product for enterprise as well as home use. Not only is VirtualBox an extremely feature rich, high performance product for enterprise customers, it is also the only professional solution that is freely available as Open Source Software under the terms of the GNU General Public License (GPL) version 2. See "About VirtualBox" for an introduction.

Comment: pure opinion, but I'd say - VB for "professionals", Parallels for "consumers" - Price vs ease.